# Unknown column in field list MySQL

Tags: mysql, fieldlist

I have a table containing mainly numbers with 1 row of column names at the top.

I ran the following query:

```
select * , (High - Low) as DiffHL from exdata3;
```

(exdata3 is table name and High, Low are existing columns. `DiffHL` is new column which I have mentioned first time in this query itself)

The query ran fine and added the new column `DiffHL` with the corresponding calculated values.

Now when I run another query after this

```
select * from exdata3 where DiffHL >100
```

I get the following error:

> error (1054) (42S22)Unknown column DiffHL in 'where clause'

I try to do any query with `DiffHL` it gives me the same above error. 
Where have I gone wrong. Do I need to create `DiffHL` first before putting/assigning values in it?
New to MySQL so bear with me.

Comment: Unless you used an `ALTER TABLE` statement, you did **not** add any columns to your table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, your first `SELECT` statement has not created column on table:

```
SELECT *, (High - Low) as DiffHL FROM exdata3;
```

Instead, it created a *"virtual"* column only accessible within it's resultset.

You should [add column manually](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html), or rewrite your `SELECT` as such:

```
SELECT *, (High - Low) as DiffHL FROM exdata3 WHERE (High - Low) > 100;
```

If you really want to add column `DiffHL` to the table, you may try to add column with following statements:

```
ALTER TABLE exdata3 ADD COLUMN DiffHL INT NULL;
-- Create an empty DiffHL column

UPDATE exdata3 SET DiffHL = High - Low;
-- Fill DiffHL column with values

SELECT * FROM exdata3;
-- Here DiffHL column is actually exists
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to reference (in the `WHERE` clause) any expression in the `SELECT` list by the **alias** assigned to the expression (within a single SELECT, without an inline view).

It is possible to reference the expression by it's **alias** in a `HAVING` clause.

For example, this would be valid:

```
SELECT t.*
     , (t.High - t.Low) AS DiffHL
  FROM exdata3 t
HAVING DiffHL > 100
^^^^^^
```

In the `WHERE` clause, you would need to repeat the expression. For example, this would be valid:

```
SELECT t.*
     , (t.High - t.Low) AS DiffHL
  FROM exdata3 t
 WHERE (t.High - t.Low) > 100 
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

you have misunderstood something:
`DiffHL` is just the name of your field in your resultset. MySQL doesn't create the field, it just names the column in your resultset.

Comment: thanks . so I need to create diffhl separately first before using it.

Answer (score 0):

MySql only temporarily added that column for display with that query

Answer (score 0):

The column does not exists in your table.

```
select * , (High - Low) as DiffHL from exdata3;
```

This query only creates an alias for the column `(High - Low)`

Use

```
select * from exdata3 where (High - Low) >100
```

Answer (score 0):

Alias name u ran in first time query, you have to define like this. Can you try it?

```
select * from exdata3 where DiffHL >100
```

to

```
select * from exdata3 where (High - Low) > 100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * , (High - Low) as DiffHL from exdata3
```

In above query you are aliasing (High - Low) to DiffHL it will not add the new column to your existing table.

Try below correct query:

```
select * , (High - Low) as DiffHL from exdata3 where DiffHL >100
```